# Подключение к mysql из Perl через SRS::MyDBI

Tags: mysql, perl

Скрипт на перл (Catalyst Framework) не может подключиться к mysql, ругается на сокет.

Сообщение об ошибке:

> `[error] Caught exception in engine "SRS::MyDBI connect('database=test; mysql_read_default_file=/www/srs/config/serverconfigs/myperl.cnf; mysql_socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock; mysql_read_default_group=perl; host=localhost','test',...) failed: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (40) at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/Catalyst.pm line 1951`

При этом сокета /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock не создается.

Также при этом mysql адекватно работает в связке Apache + MySQL + php.

В качестве ОС выступает openSUSE.

Как поправить это дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в **myperl.cnf** у тебя наверно **mysql_socket** прописан.

```
[client]
mysql_socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Закоменти его.
Из ошибки видно, что он и не пытается на **ip:port** , а идет на **файл-сокет**. Ищи это место. Или для сервера mysql - укажи, что бы он создавал файл-сокет

```
[mysqld]
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

У mysql-сервера есть свой myperl.cnf(наверняка у него имя my.cnf - ищи его в /etc/... или в /usr/... А лучше так "find /etc/ -name *.cnf")

Comment: у меня он "/var/db/mysql/my.cnf"

Comment: Да, это помогло. Убрал упоминания сокета, всё заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо **localhost** в конфиге для подключения указать IP, например, **127.0.0.1**

Comment: а не 127.0.0.1? =)

Comment: сорри ... очепЯталса :)